# How to factorize the polynomial $ 6x^4 - 11x^3 - 30x^2 + 29x - 6 $

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Using an online service I can see that the polynomial $$ 6x^4 - 11x^3 - 30x^2 + 29x - 6 $$ can be factorized as $$ (3 x-1) (2 x-1) (x+2) (x-3) $$ using the Rational Root Theorem, but how is it applied?

Comment: Guess the roots yourself... (until you are left with a polynomial of order 2 which is trivial to solve)

Comment: The first degree factors of a polynomial correspond to its roots, and the Rational Roots Theorem simplifies for us what rational numbers there are to check.  See also synthetic division for a method of checking a root.

Answer (score 1):

Factor both the leading coefficient and the constant at the end. All rational solutions will be of the form $\pm\frac p q$, where $q$ is a factor of the leading coefficient and $p$ is a factor of the constant. From there, guess any of those roots until you get one rights.

Comment: Don't forget that factors may be negative

Answer (score 0):

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), if $\frac{p}{q}$ is a factor of $P(x)$, then $p$ is a factor of, in your case, $-6$, and $q$ is a factor of $6$. So, the possibilities are:

$$
1, -1, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{6}, -\frac{1}{6} \\
2, -2, \frac{2}{2}, -\frac{2}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, -\frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{6}, -\frac{2}{6},
\\ 3, -3, \frac{3}{2}, -\frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{3}, -\frac{3}{3}, \frac{3}{6}, -\frac{3}{6},
\\ 6, -6, \frac{6}{2}, -\frac{6}{2}, \frac{6}{3}, -\frac{6}{3}, \frac{6}{6}, -\frac{6}{6}
$$

Now it is just a matter of checking each one of them, it is not that hard because many of the numbers that appear in the list are not unique.

Comment: Usually, one supposes $\frac pq$  is irreducible…

Comment: Yes, but I wanted the answer to be as clear as possible seeing that OP is in HS.

Comment: Don't they know what irreducible fractions are since the end of elementary school?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I believed that if I just wrote the irreducible fractions, it might not be clear to the OP how I came up with that list. Doing it this way, allows them to learn how to systematically factorize other polynomials with integer coefficients. If you think I am wrong, please feel free to downvote.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong – I just gave my point of view, which is slightly different from yours, and not necessarily the best. Anyway, I never downvote.